# iOS-Masterviewcontroller does not show up

Tags: ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I've been struggling with a very strange problem. In my iPad storyboard I drag a UISplitViewController. To the detail view controller I put a UIImage and set its image to an image. And I do the same thing to the master view controller. I do this just to see both master and detail view controllers display in landscape mode. But when I launch the app in iPad simulator, only the detail view controller captures the whole screen area and master does not show up. I tried setting the orientation of the split view controller to Landscape so that  make it start in landscape mode but that did not help. I know I'm missing something here. What is that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. It seems I have to set both master and detail view controllers to support certain orientations. It means just dragging a view controller to the the storyboard, making it the detail/master view controller and putting an image inside won't work. We have to create a subclass of UIViewController and set the classes in the storyboard to these newly created UIViewController custom subclasses. It's because we need to implement shouldAutoRotate... method in both view controllers.

Comment: I've the same problem now. Only detail view shows up. I could not understand you did. Can you explain me a little bit. 

I've master as well as detail view set with separate view controllers. and shouldAutoRotate is set to return true.

Comment: forgot to set the appropriate ViewController for the master. i left it as default UIViewController.